# How can I install a printer using .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing

I have an .INF for a virtual printer that I need to install from a .NET Application. I have done this before using batch scripts, but I am looking for a snippet of code to do this in the .NET Framework.

There's nothing particular about the printer .INF, so any code that installs a printer from an INF in C# or VB.NET will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is possible via interop to native win32 APIs, but I've found its much, much easier just to use a System.Diagnostics.Process() to call into printui.dll via:

`rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /?`

Perhaps you're already using that in the mentioned batch script, but if not the parameters are documented here: [PrintUI.DLL User's Guide and Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/overview/printuidll.mspx)

Just be sure to test it against all operation systems you need to support.  Some options either do not exist in all Windows releases or have been renamed (although I think they're the more esoteric options - installing an .INF will likely work across the board).

Comment: Link is broken =(

Answer (score 5):

You are going to want to look at the WMI objects available.  These give you a finer control of the local machine settings.  Take a look at the [WMI code creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&DisplayLang=en) from Microsoft, I believe this will generate some example code you can leverage to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Administering Printer Settings in C# for Flexible Printing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PrinterAdmin.aspx)

see this article, it uses an MS Platform SDK DLL called PRNADMIN to manage printers, printer-drivers, printer-ports, ...etc.

I personally use it in a commercial project to install a printer driver and change the printer port to local port to intercept the Postscript. and it works like a Charm.

Alternatively you can use some pre-installed vbscripts that come with windows in C:\Windows\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts and here is a an articles for them:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771846.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* the ideal solution, but if nobody else answers, you can create a temp batch file and invoke that through C#/VB.NET.

Someone else will probably know a more natural way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the setup APIs using PINVOKE or a native COM object.